# Plotting a bar plot of two variables and a line plot of third variable on a single plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar plot (with `position ='identity', stat = 'identity'`) and a line plot on the same plot against months using ggplot2 package in R.

My data consists of 3 mainly concerned values

1- Global irradiance 
2- Diffuse irradiance
3- Temperature

To make a bar plot, I have merged the values of Global and Diffuse irradiances in one molten dataframe. Whereas I have kept temperature values separate in an initial dataframe as I don't want it's bar plot with the irradiance values.

Now problem is I am unable to make ggplot from two different dataframes. The error I am getting using this approach is

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

even though class of both datasets is dataframe now.

On the other hand, I am confused on how to include my values in a single dataframe that I can plot all them together as bar and line plots.

My piece of code for data is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(reshape2)

data <- "U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Data//PVPlanner//PVPlanner.csv"

data <- read.table(data,skip = 36, header = T,  sep=";")
data <- data.frame(data[1:12,])
data$Month <- factor(data$Month,levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
```

whereas my data looks like:

```
Month GHId GHIm Diffd Diffm  T24
1    Jan 3.27  101  0.92    29 13.3
2    Feb 3.92  110  1.23    34 13.3
3    Mar 5.30  164  1.58    49 13.9
4    Apr 6.18  185  1.89    57 14.9
5    May 6.93  215  2.00    62 16.4
6    Jun 7.53  226  1.80    54 18.4
7    Jul 7.42  230  1.87    58 21.1
8    Aug 7.06  219  1.58    49 22.0
9    Sep 5.97  179  1.39    42 21.3
10   Oct 4.50  140  1.26    39 18.7
11   Nov 3.53  106  0.99    30 15.9
12   Dec 2.90   90  0.86    27 13.3
```

The code for making a molten dataframe out of my data is:

```
dfd <- melt(data[,c('Month','GHId','Diffd')],id.vars = 1)
```

The code for my ggplot is:

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(dfd,aes(x = Month,y = value,fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "identity")+geom_line(data,aes(Month, data[,6]), col=red)
```

I am trying to make this kind of plot:
[image]

I am looking forward to getting guidance on the type of approach that I can take either to work on a single dataframes or to call values from two different dataframes.

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I was able to spot out my mistake, If there are values from two dataframes we need to mentioned properly where exactly data is in our code like `data = dfd` in both the `geom`

OR

We need to code using exact arrangement of the code as mentioned in the function documentation!